# remove weird characters

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have imported the wordpress database and full source and implemented in my local server. I started working on it and i have also updated the wordpress version and also the plugins.

now the problem is that there are weird characters coming in my posts. such as â€™ instead of '.
So now shall i remove this from everywhere now. i have lots of posts and i dont want to do laborious work. can we have fire some query on wordpress database and remove this character..

Comment: Congratulations, your character sets have become screwed up.

Comment: try checking the char set of the database file you are importing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the database collation to `UTF-8-GENERAL`

[charset in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769159/charset-in-mysql)

Comment: and the page your displaying to utf-8, and the connection.