# How can i store Hindi data in xampp PHPmyadmin?

Tags: php, zend-framework

**How can i store Hindi data in Mysql?**

I want to code using zend.

I created 1 table in Mysql, I set collation as utf8_general_ci.

Comment: May this help's you ->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198701/storing-and-displaying-unicode-string-using-php-and-mysql

Comment: Use utf_unicode_ci in MySQL Table.

Comment: This might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769159/charset-in-mysql/5769244#5769244

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use UTF-16 rather than UTF-8. See: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,86499,86910

Answer (score 0):

As you are coding using ZEND PHP Framework, just before the SQL Query for insert/select add the 2 lines for Setting NAMES & Character Set:

```
$dbhost = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';
$dbuser = 'xyz';
$dbpass = 'xxxxxx';
$dbname = 'yyyy';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die  ('Error connecting to mysql');


    mysql_select_db($dbname);   
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    mysql_query("set characer set utf8");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename etc...");
```

Comment: Dear Vrushali, please post whether the method which i suggested worked perfectly OR it required some changes etc. (I would also like to know the working solution). Thanks